# Image planes greyed out when opening blender file

Tags: animation, image, 2d

Im working on an animation and ive imported the background and props as plane pngs with transperancy but when i reopened my file everything was greyed out. I keyed the movement of everything and I really don't want to have to reimport and re-key everything. How do I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the Viewport Shading Mode in the top right corner is set to solid:
[image: solid]
When you reopen a blend file the Viewport Shading Mode is always set to solid and nearly everything is displayed as grey mesh.

Change it to Material Preview or Rendered Mode (the both right buttons of the screenshot). Then you should see the textures again.